# How does MongoDB's time to live index work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When MongoDB uses a TTL index does it just call `.remove()` on all of the documents that are flagged for deletion? If yes does that mean that my `.pre('remove')` middleware will still get called every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) based deletion of expired documents occurs within the MongoDB server, so Mongoose middleware will not be called.

There isn't any way to get notified when documents expire and are deleted. If you need that functionality then you should implement your own document expiration instead of using a TTL index.